# Trouble Migrating from Shared DB to Dev Plan

Tags: heroku

I just followed the steps to migrate my very small shared db to Heroku's new "dev" plan.  Everything went very smoothly until I tried `$ heroku addons:remove shared-database`

I received the following error:

```
    $ heroku addons:remove shared-database
-----> Removing shared-database from [my_app]... failed
 !     Shared databases cannot be removed
```

I have confirmed that my DATABASE_URL matches my HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_[COLOR]_URL, and that my app is fully functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Heroku on the Data team. We're sorry about that: the problem you observed was a temporary problem on our end, not a problem with your code. Please try again, it was an issue on the bamboo stack specifically.

As an aside, consider [using the cedar stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maximizing-availability/#cedar). :)

Comment: BTW, it might be obvious to people with more experience than me, but why do you recommend the cedar stack?

Comment: Glad it worked. The cedar stack is better in so many ways that it's impossible to explain here. This article touches on it briefly: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maximizing-availability/#cedar